# Calculate weights based on variance of multiple columns and calculate weighted sum

Tags: r, sumproduct

I would like to do the following in R -

1. Calculate variances of columns
2. Calculate the weights of each of the columns : variance[i]/sum(variances)
3. Calculate the weighted sum

The data frame (as an example) would be

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18436, 18437, 18438, 18439), class = "Date"), 
    `BIB_Level 1` = c(261, 278, 113, 187), `BIB_Level 2` = c(230, 
    141, 280, 132), `BIB_Level 3` = c(242, 176, 149, 274)), .Names = c("Date", 
"BIB_Level 1", "BIB_Level 2", "BIB_Level 3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Example: The variances of the columns in the example are

```
> sapply(wideDf[,-1],FUN = var,na.rm=T)
BIB_Level 1 BIB_Level 2 BIB_Level 3 
   5720.917    5110.917    3332.250
```

The weights would be :

```
> sapply(wideDf[,-1],FUN = var,na.rm=T)/sum(sapply(wideDf[,-1],FUN = var,na.rm=T))
BIB_Level 1 BIB_Level 2 BIB_Level 3 
  0.4039031   0.3608364   0.2352605
```

The weighted sum for the first row would be

```
> (261*0.4039031)+(230*0.3608364)+(242*0.2352605)
[1] 245.3441
```

I need a column for the weighted sum appended to the data frame.

How can I write this as a single chunk of code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sweep` with `rowSums` :

```
val <- sapply(wideDf[,-1],FUN = var,na.rm=TRUE)
weight <- val/sum(val)
wideDf$weighted_sum <- rowSums(sweep(wideDf[-1], 2, weight, `*`))
wideDf

#        Date BIB_Level 1 BIB_Level 2 BIB_Level 3 weighted_sum
#1 2020-06-23         261         230         242     245.3441
#2 2020-06-24         278         141         176     204.5688
#3 2020-06-25         113         280         149     181.7291
#4 2020-06-26         187         132         274     187.6217
```

Or transpose the data multiply with `weight` and take sum of columns.

```
wideDf$weighted_sum <- colSums(t(wideDf[-1]) * weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why this all has to be in a single chunk of code, but the following would do it.

Note that the diagonal entries of the result of `var` (covariance function) on a matrix are indeed the variances. But it's worth computing it once rather than multiple times.

By transposing the `wideDf`, you can use `R`'s column-wise operations to quickly multiply each column (originally each row) with a vector of weights.

```
wideDf$weighted_sums <- colSums(t(wideDf[, -1]) * diag(var(wideDf[, -1], na.rm = TRUE)) / sum(diag(var(wideDf[, -1], na.rm = TRUE))))
wideDf
        Date BIB_Level 1 BIB_Level 2 BIB_Level 3 weightedSums
1 2020-06-23         261         230         242     245.3441
2 2020-06-24         278         141         176     204.5688
3 2020-06-25         113         280         149     181.7291
4 2020-06-26         187         132         274     187.6217
```